# How to push non empty object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

**Input:**

```
var npi = {'test1':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test2':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test3':{'address':'cleveland','num':'12'},'test4':{'address':'hostun','num':'12'}}
```

**Expected output:**

```
var array = ['cleaveland','hostun']
```

i.e push only if an address is available.

**My code:**

```
for(var i = 0;i < = 4;i++){
    if(npi.test+''+i.address) {
        array.push(npi.test+''+i.address);
    }
}
```

But it is not working since I did a mistake, can anyone please help me?
 Thanks.

Comment: `npi.test` = undefined. then if you do `+ ' ' + i.address` you end up with `if ("undefined undefined") { ... }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the keys of the `npi` object, filter them to only get ones that are `'testN'` (where N is any number) and that have an `.address` that is not blank, then map that:

```js
var npi = {'not':{},'nsi':{}, 'test1':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test2':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test3':{'address':'cleveland','num':'12'},'test4':{'address':'hostun','num':'12'}}

var array = Object.keys(npi)
  .filter(function(k) { return /^test\d+$/.test(k) && npi[k].address })
  .map(function(k) { return npi[k].address })

console.log(array)
```

Further reading:

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Hi nnnn,how to perform if I have object as

Comment: npi = {'not':{},'nsi:{},'test1':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test2':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test3':{'address':'cleveland','num':'12'},'test4':{'address':'hostun','num':'12'}}

Comment: Well this does not guarantee order, while the OP's code (if working) would

Comment: where i have to push only test object address

Comment: @Duster Check my answer.

Comment: @Duster - I updated my answer to check that the name of the key matches the `testN` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var objNPI = Json.parse(npi); for(var i = 0;i < = 4;i++){ var prop = 
objNPI[i].address; if(prop) { array.push(objNPI); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var npi = {
    'test1': {
        'address': '',
        'num': '12'
    },
    'test2': {
        'address': '',
        'num': '12'
    },
    'test3': {
        'address': 'cleveland',
        'num': '12'
    },
    'test4': {
        'address': 'hostun',
        'num': '12'
    }
};

var addressArr = [];

var objKeys = Object.keys(npi);
for (var i = 0; i < objKeys.length; i++) {
    if (npi[objKeys[i]].address) {
        addressArr.push(npi[objKeys[i]].address);
    }
}

console.log(addressArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem:

```
var array = [];
var keys = Object.keys(npi).slice();
for(key of keys){
  if(npi[key].address != ''){
    array.push(npi[key].address);
  }
}
```

Comment: npi = {'not':{},'nsi:{},'test1':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test2':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test3':{'address':'cleveland','num':'12'},'test4':{'address':'hostun','num':'12'}}

Comment: i need to consider test only

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you are accessing your properties in your object. You need to use **bracket** notation for accessing properties dynamically, like so.

```js
var npi = {'test1':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test2':{'address':'','num':'12'},'test3':{'address':'cleveland','num':'12'},'test4':{'address':'hostun','num':'12'}};

var array = []

for(var i = 1;i <= 4;i++){
  // access npi test properties dynamically with bracket [] syntax
  var address = npi["test"+i].address;
  if(address) {
    array.push(address);
  }
}

console.log(array);
```